How to Create a Horizontally Aligned Single-Selection Radio Button Group in FlexboxLayout in Android?
I'm trying to create a group of radio buttons inside a FlexboxLayout so that they are aligned horizontally and wrap to the next line when the screen space is insufficient. However, I also want to ensure that only one radio button can be selected at a time, which is a feature of RadioGroup.
I'm using FlexboxLayout to achieve the horizontal wrapping, but I can't enforce the single selection behavior without a RadioGroup.
How can I create this layout with a FlexboxLayout while still ensuring that only one radio button can be selected at a time?
Here's the code I'm using:
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:flexbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        android:id="@+id/flexbox_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        flexbox:flexWrap="wrap"
        flexbox:flexDirection="row">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Option 1"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Option 2"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Option 3"/>

    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
</LinearLayout>

